# split customDimensions into 3 jsons and then project using kusto query

Tags: c#, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

So, I have a Kusto query

```
requests
| where customDimensions has'Scope' and customDimensions['Scope'] != 'Unauthenticated' and cloud_RoleName == 'cloud1'
| project x = tostring(customDimensions['x'], y = tostring(customDimensions['y'] ...
```

i want the split my `customDimensions` values into 3 jsons.
then project it as

```
| project json1 = json1, json2 = json2, json3 = json3
```

but i not able to group/split the customDimensions i tried dynamic, datatable but they dont take variables as inputs
for e.g `dynamic_to_json(dynamic({'x': customDimensions['x'] }))` throws an error same for the data tables

Error that the above statement gives is `it should end with '}'` where clearly my syntax is correct. i feel it somehow does not accesses the customDimensions variable inside dynamic or datatable

could anyone please guide me on this..

I want the output as

```
| json1 | json2 | json3 |
|{...}  | {...} | {...} |
```

all the 3 json's will be created from customDimensions or other columns of the same table;

about customDimensions https://camerondwyer.com/2020/05/26/how-to-use-application-insights-custom-properties-in-azure-monitor-log-kusto-queries/

assume there is any thing in customDimensions like

```
customDimensions = {x:X, y:Y, a:A, ...}
```

```
json1 should have {x, y z}
json2 should have {r, t, p,}
json3 should have {w, m, n}
```

Comment: Data sample? Error message?

Comment: Can you share a **significant** data sample, preferably using datatable + required results?

Comment: TBD offline :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following a conversation with @Sandeep Ranjan:

The challenge here was to extract fields from a JSON document stored as dynamic and then pack them together to 3 new separate JSON documents.

Extracting fields is straightforward, E,g.:

```
customDimensions.myfield
```

or

```
customDimensions["myfield"]
```

The later can be used for fields names with spaces and/or special characters, E.g.:

```
customDimensions["my field"]
customDimensions["my-field!"]
```

Packing the fields can be done with 3 different functions that are synonyms to each other.
Those functions are [pack_dictionary()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packdictionaryfunction), [pack()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packfunction) & [bag_pack()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packfunction)

Here is a quick sample:

```
let requests = datatable(customDimensions:dynamic) [dynamic({"x":1, "y":2, "z":3, "a":"hello", "b":"world", "k1":"v1", "k2":"v2", "k3":"v3", "k4":"v4"})];
requests
| project-rename cd = customDimensions // just to make things a little bit shorter
| extend json_1 = pack_dictionary("x",cd .x, "y", cd.y, "z", cd.z)
| extend json_2 = pack_dictionary("a", cd.a, "b", cd.b)
| extend json_3 = pack_dictionary("k1", cd.k1, "k2", cd.k2, "k3", cd.k3, "k4", cd.k4)
```

| cd | json_1 | json_2 | json_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"x":1,"y":2,"z":3,"a":"hello","b":"world","k1":"v1","k2":"v2","k3":"v3","k4":"v4"} | {"x":1,"y":2,"z":3} | {"a":"hello","b":"world"} | {"k1":"v1","k2":"v2","k3":"v3","k4":"v4"} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22Qy07DMBBF95X6DyOvEim0ymOVih1/gVDl2CPixomLPYWkwL8zsWFTKi/mXGvmzsMigce3CwYK8AhaEr/OYqYugdz4ZEacgnFTaPUyydGoHJ5/KfsUs2jLAsQi2orDVbQ1Byla0aO1TrDoWHw4b/UqhpLVexmxWrGKWK9YR2xWbMR3/nLYbv7m2m6%204OzdCRU9eOTeCErzsLcjwn4PJ/4DcjDKAYF6M70GkGANkUXoDEHonSf0qyfOhJOGU3DTsWS/s1TDURtFbCb9kvF6BTfazXHFgpvulrhmxGt%2061Hd85ApW8ZbROz%20Fdb3CocypQ9lOlcSVTpYEnU6WRJN/gPubsuxzAEAAA==)